# Multiprocessing with GPU in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I need to compute multiple deep models in parallel and average their results. My job runs forever after finishing computation with `GPU 0`.

```
def model_train(self, params):
    from nn_arch import nn_models
    X, y, gpu_no = params
    print("GPU NO ", gpu_no)
    with tf.device('/gpu:' + str(gpu_no)):
        model1 = nn_models.lenet5()
        early_callback = CustomCallback()
        model1.fit(X, y, batch_size=256, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_callback],
                   verbose=1,
                   epochs=1)
    return model1
```

And my main method below. `In this case I have 2 GPUs`

```
def main(self, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
    random_buckets = self.get_random()
    X = [X_train[random_buckets[k]] for k in sorted(random_buckets)]
    y = [y_train[random_buckets[j]] for j in sorted(random_buckets)]

    params = zip(X, y, [0, 1])
    models = pool1.map(self.model_train, params)
```

How do I train multiple models in parallel with Keras. (Data Parallel Approach)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before compiling the model in keras. Add this line

model = make_parallel(model, 2)

where 2 is the number of GPUs available.

The make_parallel function is available in this file. Just import the file in your code and your code will be executed on multiple GPUs.

https://github.com/kuza55/keras-extras/blob/master/utils/multi_gpu.py

make_parallel is a simple function that:

- It instantiates a copy of your model on the N GPUs you tell it to
- It splits your batch into N evenly sized smaller batches
- It passes each smaller batch into the corresponding model
- It concatenates the outputs of the models

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to multi-GPU TensorFlow tutorials as a reference.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.7/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py